# comparing the values of complex norms

Tags: complex-numbers

If $a,b\in \mathbb{C}$ how can we compare the size of $\lvert a+b \rvert^2$ and $\lvert a \rvert^2+\lvert b \rvert^2$? Do we have $\lvert a+b \rvert^2\leq \lvert a \rvert^2+\lvert b \rvert^2$?

Comment: In this case you can think of complex numbers as vectors. Then check out the triangle inequality.

Comment: @MattiP. You're forgetting that these absolute values are squared.

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact that $|z|^2=z\bar{z}$ to write
$$|a+b|^2=(a+b)(\bar{a}+\bar{b})=|a|^2+|b|^2+(a\bar{b}+\bar{a}b)=|a|^2+|b|^2+2\Re(a\bar{b}).$$
So we can possibly have $\Re(a\bar{b})>0$, in which case the left side can be larger than $|a|^2+|b|^2$.

If $\Re(a\bar{b})>0$, then $|a+b|^2 > |a|^2+|b|^2$.

If $\Re(a\bar{b})\leq 0$, then $|a+b|^2 \leq |a|^2+|b|^2$.

Answer (score 0):

We do have
$$
|a+b| \leq |a|+|b|
$$
However, with the squares in your expression, it's not true in general. For instance:
$$
|2+2|^2 = 16 > 8 = |2|^2 + |2|^2
$$

Answer (score 0):

$\vert a+b\vert ^2= \vert a\vert ^2+ \vert b\vert ^2+ 2R(a\bar b) \le  \vert a\vert ^2+ \vert b\vert ^2+2\vert a\vert \vert b\vert\le(\vert a\vert+\vert b \vert)^2$. Hence $$\vert a+b\vert \le \vert a\vert+ \vert b\vert $$ But nothing can be said about $R(a \bar b)$. I may be positive or negative or even zero. So the sign of inequality can be anything in the former case, i.e. when you take squares.